# HDInsight - Cluster is not responding

Tags: hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I just begun to study HDInsight but It's not working properly..

When I install HDInsight new, it works well but If I reboot or restart a system,
server can't recognize a cluster.

The message shows like "Your cluster "local (hdfs)" is not responding. 
Please click here to navigate to the cluster." and work nothing.

How can I solve this problem?

I know some issues in applicationpoolidentity and so I tired to change it
using powershell but still doesn't work..

I am running it on Win7 ultimate with IIS 7.5

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would ask you to check all the HDInsight specific services are running in your cluster as shown below after restart:

[image]
If any of the service is not started, start it. Next what you could do is format namenode name by using command and it sould

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

After you format you will see new name node folder created @ C:\hadoop\hdfs\nn with some files in it. If you still see the problem contact HDInsight Support forum [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/hdinsight).